# How do I auto-update a table queried from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called **result_management_report** and then another tabled called **rmr_only_only**. **rmr_only_report** is just queried from the former table like this...

CREATE TABLE rmr_only_report AS
     SELECT * FROM result_management_report
     WHERE act_id IN ('a','b','c','d','e')

When I add new records to **result_management_report**, I noticed that **rmr_only_report** is not updated with the newest records. How do I set up a process that auto-updates the second table every time new records are added to the first?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a table, create a view.

```
DROP TABLE rmr_only_report;

CREATE VIEW rmr_only_report
AS
SELECT *
       FROM result_management_report
       WHERE act_id IN ('a',
                        'b',
                        'c',
                        'd',
                        'e');
```

The view will always have the current result of the query.

Answer (score 1):

It will **NEVER** update as it is a different table.

Also **do not create table from table**. It is a waste of resource, time, your effort, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE rmr_only_report AS SELECT * FROM result_management_report WHERE act_id IN ('a','b','c','d','e')
```

can be changed into

```
create or replace view rmr_only_report as ...
```

This will update as you wish.

Cheers.